# Unable to get images to display in Image Panel in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

The project I am working on requires the user to create a GUI that deals the user five cards from a shuffled deck (using a linked list, but that part's not important, at least I don't think so). So far, I've managed to get the mechanics working, but the GUI just refuses to work. I copy-pasted from the instructor's example that showed us how to get an image to display, but even though the program runs, when I click the 'Deal cards' button, nothing happens.

Here is the code:

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package projectone;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Geoff
 */
public class CardDealer extends JFrame {

   private JPanel imagePanel;     // To hold the label
   private JPanel buttonPanel;    // To hold a button
   private JLabel imageLabelOne, imageLabelTwo, imageLabelThree, 
   imageLabelFour, imageLabelFive;     // To show an image
   private JButton button;        // To get an image
   public static Object[] theHand; //five cards hand


public static void main(String[] args) 
{






   LinkedStack theDeck = new LinkedStack();

   theDeck = theDeck.theCards();





    System.out.println("List print test\n");
    System.out.println(theDeck.toString());


    theDeck.shuffle(theDeck);
    System.out.println("List shuffle print test\n");
    System.out.println(theDeck.toString());

    Object[] hand =
    {
    theDeck.pop(),
    theDeck.pop(),
    theDeck.pop(),
    theDeck.pop(),
    theDeck.pop(),       
    };


    System.out.println("Hand print test\n");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hand));

    theHand = hand;

   new CardDealer();
   }
   /**
  Constructor
   */

   public CardDealer()
   {
  // Set the title.
  setTitle("Card Dealer");

  // Specify an action for the close button.
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  // Create a BorderLayout manager.
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));

  // Build the panels.
  buildImagePanel();
  buildButtonPanel();

  // Add the panels to the content pane.
  add(imagePanel);
  add(buttonPanel);

  // Pack and display the window.
  pack();
  setVisible(true);
}

/**
  The buildImagePanel method adds a label to a panel.
*/

private void buildImagePanel()
{
   // Create a panel.
   imagePanel = new JPanel();
   imagePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
   imagePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 5));

  // Create a label.
  imageLabelOne = new JLabel();
  imageLabelTwo = new JLabel();
  imageLabelThree = new JLabel();
  imageLabelFour = new JLabel();
  imageLabelFive = new JLabel();

  // Add the label to the panel.
  imagePanel.add(imageLabelOne);
  imagePanel.add(imageLabelTwo);
  imagePanel.add(imageLabelThree);
  imagePanel.add(imageLabelFour);
  imagePanel.add(imageLabelFive);
}

/**
  The buildButtonPanel method adds a button
  to a panel.
*/

private void buildButtonPanel()
{

  // Create a panel.
  buttonPanel = new JPanel();


  // Create a button.
  button = new JButton("Deal");



  // Register an action listener with the button.
  button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

  // Add the button to the panel.
  buttonPanel.add(button);
}

/**
  Private inner class that handles the event when
  the user clicks the button.
*/

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
     // Read the image file into an ImageIcon object.
      ImageIcon card1, card2, card3, card4, card5;
       card1 = new ImageIcon(theHand[0].toString() + ".jpg");
       card2 = new ImageIcon(theHand[1].toString() + ".jpg");
       card3 = new ImageIcon(theHand[2].toString() + ".jpg");
       card4 = new ImageIcon(theHand[3].toString() + ".jpg");
       card5 = new ImageIcon(theHand[4].toString() + ".jpg");

     // Display the image in the label.
     imageLabelOne.setIcon(card1);
     imageLabelTwo.setIcon(card2);
     imageLabelThree.setIcon(card3);
     imageLabelFour.setIcon(card4);
     imageLabelFive.setIcon(card5);



     // Pack the frame again to accomodate the 
     // new size of the label.
     pack();
  }
 }



}
```

The problem is, when I click the 'Deal' button, the five images (card1 through card5) do not display. The ImageIcons are all pointing to the right filenames, I double checked. They just don't show up in the panel. Did I miss something? Here is the output:

[Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu81A.png)

Comment: try changing this 2 line in `CardDealer` constructor as follow
`add(imagePanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);`
        `add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);`

Comment: Where are the images located, relative to your source?

Comment: I copied them all over the project directory (using Netbeans) in a panic. However, Fast Snail's advice seems to have worked, and the jpg's actually display now. Thanks. I can't seem to find the thank/solution button though?

Comment: @FastSnail Please upgrade your comment to an answer so the OP can accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are adding  to border layout .so you have to specify the position of border layout, you want components to be added .by default it adds to center .also you cannot add 2 or more components to same position.

so the problem in your code you don't specify the position.you are adding 2 components to center.

to fix this specify the position like this

```
add(imagePanel); // same as `BorderLayout.CENTER` (default)
add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```